# Cloud function random spike in execution time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a very simple cloud function running via firebase. This function accepts a parameter, does a lookup in a firebase store, and then returns the document value that it finds. Before querying that second database, it also queries another firestore to check if the return value was supposed to be overridden (an override table).

95% of the time, this function executes in less than 100ms (usually around 50ms). However, I will randomly get a function once every few minutes that takes 4-5 seconds to execute. I've set the minimum instances to 200 and the active instances never seems to peak past 40-50, so I don't think it's related to a cold start. I've also centralized all the dependencies to the file where the function execution takes place (still doubt this would have helped anyway seeing as a cold start is unlikely). The memory for the instance never goes above 200mb and the instance is set at 256.

I'm drawing a blank on what could cause the function execution to randomly spike that high. The relevant code block is below:

```
let doc
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
var db = admin.firestore()
var flowerRef = db.collection("flower").doc(flowerName)
try {
    doc = await flowerRef.get()
} catch (error) {
    throw Error(error)
}
if (!doc.exists) {
    return {}
} else {
    let data = doc.data()
    data.flower = flower
    return data
}
```

Comment: You say _This function accepts a parameter, does a lookup in a firebase ... then Before querying that second database, it also queries another firestore_. How many total collections are you querying? Have you thought about querying them in parallel?

Comment: i could for sure but that still wouldn't explain why only certain executions were randomly longer than others.

Comment: 40-50 instances sounds like you have good amount of traffic, what's your qps? could you be hitting a hotspot in firestore?

Comment: qps generally is around 10-20 during heavier periods and ~2 in lighter periods.

Comment: I would suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to inspect your project and further investigate what's happening on the random spike in the execution time.